# JS частичное глубокое копирование

Tags: javascript

Необходимо в объектах менять данные частями, изменившиеся ключ приходят в виде строки

```
'<key>.<key>....'
```

---

```
function updateByPath(path, from, to){
    let target = {from, to}
    for (const key of path.split('.')) {
      target.from = target.from[key];
      target.to   = target.to[key];
    }
    target.to = target.from
}

let FOO = {
   a: 'hello',
   b: {
      test: 1
   }
}

let BAR = {
    a: '1111',
    b: {
       test: 12
    }
}

console.log(`FOO: ${JSON.stringify(FOO)}`);
console.log(`BAR: ${JSON.stringify(BAR)}`);
updateByPath('b.test', FOO, BAR);

console.log(`FOO: ${JSON.stringify(FOO)}`);
console.log(`BAR: ${JSON.stringify(BAR)}`);
```

Похоже, что я переписываю только ссылки, а как переписать значения не могу понять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, вам нужен способ определить, что вы на последней итерации, и тогда изменить характер присваивания. Например, так:

```js
function updateByPath(path, from, to){
    let target = { from, to };
    const keys = path.split('.');

    keys.forEach((key, index) => {
      if (index === keys.length - 1) {
        target.to[key] = target.from[key];
      } else {
        target.from = target.from[key];
        target.to = target.to[key];
      }
    });
}

let FOO = {
   a: 'hello',
   b: {
      test: 1
   }
};

let BAR = {
    a: '1111',
    b: {
       test: 12
    }
};

console.log(`FOO: ${JSON.stringify(FOO)}`);
console.log(`BAR: ${JSON.stringify(BAR)}`);
updateByPath('b.test', FOO, BAR);

console.log(`FOO: ${JSON.stringify(FOO)}`);
console.log(`BAR: ${JSON.stringify(BAR)}`);
```